# how can I simulate a spinner selection in flashbuilder 4.6 / actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flex4.6

I have a situation where Im using a datespinner component to allow the user to specify a specific date which is used for a search function.  I've just added gestures for left and right swipe that will advance the date or go to the previous date, and it sets the spinner component to that newly produced date...  I want to know how I go about programmatically making the spinner perform the action that is triggered when a person changes a day month or year value.

right now the function the date spinner calls (when changes to the spinner values are made) is:

```
protected function datespinner1_changeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
      .....   do some stuff here .....
    }
```

so I wanted to call this function again elsewhere can I do that?  I tried the following but it didnt work:

```
datespinner1_changeHandler(event:Event);
```

thanks in advance for any help you can provide on this.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't actually use the event object in the "do some stuff here" part you can change the function to have a default null parameter like

```
protected function datespinner1_changeHandler(event:Event=null):void
```

then call it like

```
datespinner1_changeHandler();
```